# Can I reinstall Windows 7 without touching my existing dual boot Ubuntu installation?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have dual boot configured with Windows 7 (32bit) and Ubuntu 12.04(64bit). I installed Ubuntu after windows, now my windows is corrupt due to some virus and I need to reinstall it. Currently when I start my PC, grub loader comes up and I need to select Ubuntu or Windows.

I was wondering how can I install windows again and still have my Ubuntu install? Is there a way to do this?

I do not want to install Ubuntu again and lose my settings and data there.

Thanks,
Ketan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point to note: By dual boot you meant **Ubuntu not installed by wubi.**

Install windows 7 as usual in the same drive as it is now. It will replace the GRUB and ubuntu will not be bootable. But ubuntu isn't deleted. You can recover it using a simple tool `boot-repair` without complicated commands.

Boot using ubuntu disk after installation of windows 7.

Use `boot-repair` to perform a `Recomemnded Repair` . [Instructions are here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Thanks! I will try that. I hope I can format the drive that has windows?

Comment: yes. Just don't touch linux drives (swap & main directory)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer yes and no.
No you cannot install windows and expect grub to be there with a menu after you have done it.

Yes you can install windows, AFTERWARDS, using the medium you used to install ubuntu, boot to the live CD/USB. And run the grub recovery commands.

I will not clutter this answer with the grub recovery commands as you may not accept this answer.,

It is NOT particularly hard to do.

Good Luck - Mal